# MSVC: Why does use of enum without prior declaration compile?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, enums, language-lawyer, declaration

While playing around with C++, I discovered that the following code

```
enum E* kind;
int main() { }
```

compiles on MSVC v19.latest. I expected this to fail, as `E` is not declared yet. GCC and Clang give appropriate error messages

> error: use of enum 'E' without previous declaration

and

> error: ISO C++ forbids forward references to 'enum' types

respectively.

Why does above code compile on MSVC? Is MSVC not following the standard? Is it UB, a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does above code compile on MSVC?

Because you're compiling with Microsoft extensions enabled.

Like many implementations, MSVC sneakily enables them by default.

> Is MSVC not following the standard?

The C++ standard says that your code isn't valid C++. However, there is nothing stopping an implementation from *extending* the C++ langauge to give meaning to programs that are not legal C++. That's what MSVC is doing here.

If you compile with [language extensions disabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/za-ze-disable-language-extensions?view=msvc-170), MSVC v19.latest will [reject it](https://godbolt.org/z/zreP51fEx) with the error message

```
error C3432: 'E': a forward declaration of an unscoped enumeration must have an underlying type
```